# C++ defining IO Member variable with private variables

Tags: c++

I'm currently working on a project for my intro to c++ class and I'm stuck, Im told to set a private variable to CIN_ERROR (ill post code below) when istr fails at any point.

2 questions:

1. How do I tell if istr fails?
2. How can I access the private variable when defining the member function? (I've tried scoping to it but it says un-accessible).

   ```
     std::istream& read(std::istream& istr){
     if (istr /*not sure how to check if istr failed*/){
         Date::_readErrorCode = CIN_FAILED;
         /*_readErrorCode is the private variable*/
     }
   }
   ```

The function definition is:

```
std::istream& read(std::istream& istr); /*it is within the same 
class as the rest, not sure if that helped*/
```

**the exercise requirement:** 
Reads the date in following format: YYYY/MM/DD (i.e 2015/03/24) from the console. This function will not prompt anything. If istream (istr) fails at any point, it will set the _readErrorCode to CIN_FAILED and will NOT clear the istream object.

NOTE: CIN_FAILED is just a define value of 3

Comment: @ChakerMallek: It's better to discuss your answer in commentary to your answer, rather than in commentary to the question. Also, I personally would prefer such a request to be worded like "Please check my answer" rather than the imperative-sounding "check my answer". But OK, will do.

Answer (score 1):

To check if a stream has failed you can use the `fail()` member function or just conversion to `bool`. The conversion yields `true` iff. `not fail()`.

Do note that `good()` is not the opposite of `fail()`. `good()` yields `true` if none of the error flags are set, and this includes in particular the EOF flag. `fail()` checks only `badbit`. I.e., conversion to `bool` is not the same as `good()`.

The usual idiom for formatted readin, `while( stream >> variable )`, uses conversion to `bool`, i.e. it's checking `fail()`.

---

For an academic exercise you may (or may not) be expected to deal with the case where the stream has been configured to throw exceptions on failures. In that case you also need a `try ... catch` construction.

That's only for the academic because the design of iostream exception throwing is wholly impractical and thus never used: it's not an in-practice consideration. Instead of adjusting your code when encountering such a beast, one would instead identify the responsible programmer and adjust that person. So, it's wholly academical, but dealing with it may (or may not) be required for an academic exercise.

---

Regarding accessing a private variable that the compiler tells you is inaccessible, there are technical solutions (in particular Johannes Schaub's trick, working entirely within the ordinary type checking rules), but the chance of you needing such a solutions is about the same as three elephants dropping down from the sky and performing Abba's "Money money money". Or something. Much more likely you're intended to do this in a member function of the relevant class, or else use appropriate member functions of that class, about which you have provided no information at all.

Comment: what information should I exactly put? I dont quite under stand your explanation.

Comment: Hm, I *think* you're talking about the last sentence in my answer. Relevant information would be to present at least the class definition, or (verbatim) the exercise requirements. The information that you have about it.

Comment: Lol man, commenting the answer of mine or yours or the question is the same thing. By the way, +1 for the nice explanation.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I added the definition and the exercise requirement, I hope it makes it a bit clearer, also thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

For an input stream , if the specified file does not exist, it will **not** be created by the operating system, and the input stream variable will contain an error flag. This can be checked using the member function `fail()`.

> **fail()** provides a way to check the status of the last operation on the
>   input stream .
>
> **fail()** returns true if the last operation failed and returns false if
>   the operation was successful.

```
 std::istream& read(std::istream& istr){
  if (istr.fail()){
      Date::_readErrorCode = CIN_FAILED;
      /*_readErrorCode is the private variable*/
  }
}
```

Hope I Helped.

Comment: This is technically correct as far as it goes, but is (1) incomplete regarding what it addresses, because there's no mention of other flags or flag checking functions (in particular `good()`) or exceptions, and (2) a bit misleading because it accentuates "the last operation" but failure states of iostreams are persistent.

Comment: Apparently the answer quotes text from somewhere, the two sentences that each start with "fail()", but does not give a referent for that quote: a referent would be nice.

Comment: It's somewhat incomplete wrt. the OP's question, because it does not discuss the problem with access to a `private` variable. But then the OP does not provide sufficient information to resolve that except very general advices such as placing the code in a member function of the class, or using existing member functions (whatever they are).

Comment: On the positive side the mention about how input streams are not automatically created. I like that. I forgot to mention it, but it's important for correctness.

Answer (score 0):

Completely my fault on making it impossible for others to answer, however I figured out that all I was missing was a scoop;

```
  std::istream& Date::read(std::istream& istr){
  if (istr.fail){
      _readErrorCode = CIN_FAILED;
  }
}
```

read wasn't getting scooped to the Date class which is why I _readErrorCode wasn't being defined and scoping directly to a private variable wouldn't work obviously. Thanks to everyone that answered!